# inner join versus between for fast filtering

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Given a dataframe `orig_df` with 2billion+ records and the following fields:

```
id | date_int | code_type | code
```

where `id`, `code_type` and `code` are strings, and `date_int` is an integer (days since 1/1/1970).

Have three other dataframe which are used to filter `orig_df` as follows

```
(orig_df
    .join(member_df, ["id"], "leftsemi")
    .join(calendar_df, ["date_int"], "leftsemi")
    .join(useful_codes_df, ["code_type","code"], "leftsemi"))
```

The above is my current approach and it takes about 15mins to run.

`calendar_df` has consecutive days between 1/1/2015 and 12/31/2019.  I could just as well write the above as

```
(orig_df
    .filter(F.col("enc_dt_int").between(START_DT_INT,END_DT_INT)
    .join(member_df, ["id"], "leftsemi")
    .join(useful_codes_df, ["code_type","code"], "leftsemi"))
```

where `START_DT_INT` and `END_DT_INT` are dates converted to integers (as defined above).  Essentially they are 16436 and 18261.

Is there way to tell if one of these would always be faster than the other?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say overall, `filter` is better than `join` because `join` requires data shuffling. If you still experiencing slowness, try [broadcasting](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.broadcast) your smaller dataset, sometimes it could boost your join 200% faster.

The bottom line, the only "way to tell if one of these would always be faster than the other" is to run it over and over then benchmark the results.